# Git create new branch from feature branch without the branch commit history

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I want to create a new branch based on a feature branch without the commit history of the branch.
It should look like as if I had already pushed the feature branch to the master and create the new branch based on this.

So when I later compare the `[master+feature branch]-branch` with the new branch, it shows only the new added commits from the new branch and not the one from the already pushed feature branch.

I have already tried using the `--orphan` flag, but this seems to delete all history.

Comment: If you create your new branch from `feature-branch` (`git checkout -b new-branch feature-branch`), can you explain what doesn't suit your needs afterwards ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(note: perhaps I am missing something)

Simply create a new branch from feature branch :

```
git switch -c new-branch feature-branch
```

If you want to see the commits on `new-branch` that are not on `feature-branch`, just run :

```
git log --graph feature-branch..new-branch
```

If you are used to a GUI to view the history of your repo, all the GUI clients I have seen offer a way to type `feature-branch..new-branch` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- create your new branch from master (or main, the new default branch name)
- restore your index and working tree with the content from feature branch, and commit

That is:

```bash
git switch -c newBranch master
git restore --staged --worktree --source=featureBranch
git commit -m "restore featureBranch content"
```